# Parent fragment destroyed with shared element transition

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-transitions, shared-element-transition

I have a view hierarchy such as below.

- MainActivity :

  - FirstFragment :

    - SecondFragment :

In my SecondFragment, i have a `RecyclerView`. When an item is clicked, i want to open it in another `Fragment` (in full screen) so i am using the `addSharedElement()` method and everything works fine after 2 days of retro engineering it : every post i have found on StackOverFlow does not mention that in order to work, the "full-screen" fragment has to replace the first parent inside the activity.

What i first wanted was to nested the full-screen fragment inside the SecondFragment but it's impossible with this method.

I have tried everything else, at each steps of my view hierarchy & none of them is working, except if i replace my FirstFragment by my full-screen fragment.

- This is also impossible to use the transition with the `add()` method unfortunately.

The problem is that this fragment is destroyed & not recreated despite the call of `addToBackStack()`, when i press the "back-button" inside the `NavigationBar`. 
I am not really familiar with the `addToBackStack()` method & how can i get back any fragments i have added there.

**QUESTION 1** : How can i make it work either without destroying the parent fragment (FirstFragment in my view hierarchy), or without using shared element transition but achieving the same result ?

It seems that what the Transition is doing is recreating a view in the new fragment with the same width / height, x & y coordinates as the one in the previous fragment & animate it from the new fragment...

**QUESTION 2** : Would it be a bad idea to do it myself ?

**EDIT** : My goal is to close the full-screen fragment with a swipe down and as soon as the finger is moved from 10dp along the Y axis, i want to be able to reveal the previous fragment behind (the SecondFragment in my case), that's why i don't want to destroy parent fragments.